# New xfbml "Like" button + CloudFlare 503 error kills count?

Tags: html, facebook-like, xfbml, cloudflare

Recently switched to XFBML to make our page more efficient. However, we noticed that when we started using fb:like vs. the old iframe new Facebook Likes are no longer recording!

Wanted to get some insight on this. The Facebook debugger is not returning error codes so we're in the dark about what's causing this!

Code reference, everything checks out though:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/" send="false" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="90" font="arial" action="like"></fb:like>
```

**CloudFlare:** I did notice that CloudFlare was sometimes deflecting traffic from the Facebook debug/linter and wanted to know if that could be related? Here's an example request you can try: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vancitybuzz.com%2F2012%2F01%2Fwhat-lurks-below-british-columbia%2F

Thanks for the help!

**Update:** this issue is occurring on multiple methods for "like" (HTML5, etc.)

Comment: You must fix the 503 error being returned by your server.  You should be returning a 200.

Comment: That 503 would be a CloudFlare error then, since I can ping it non stop without an overload. thanks for pointing it out. I'll update this thread if I find a solution.

Comment: @DMCS Do you (or anyone else reading this) know of a list where we can find the latest Facebook IP addresses? We're working with CloudFlare to whitelist all traffic

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a list of IPs for Facebook.  Maybe CloudFlare can contact a rep at Facebook over the phone to work out a solution??

Comment: @DMCS working on it. I agree they should have a direct line themselves.

Comment: We actually have an open bug with Facebook about this (a 503 response code is intermittently being returned with their debugger tool). If you are having issues with this at all, please [contact us](http://support.cloudflare.com/cgi/discussion/new) so we can keep track of customers having the issue & report back when resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a recipe to figure this one out, but if you have the same symptoms (CloudFlare, Wordpress site, Facebook "Like" button not working in both xfbml and html5 formats) then here is what I recommend:

- Contact CloudFlare and request an update of all Whitelisted IPs
- Remove CloudFlare setting to check for browser integrity
- Clear and/or change all cache-control headers
- Wait a day so CF servers have a chance to propogate
- Perform a linter/debugger reset on "likes" that lost count: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
- Add your Facebook ID to the meta tag
- Like items you want "rejuvenated"
- Wait one more day for Facebook servers to propagate and sync accordingly

The key was giving the problem time, since both CloudFlare and Facebook have vast servers that require syncing mechanisms, and may take days to catch up.

Answer (score 3):

We have actually identified the issue (worked with Facebook) and we believe a proper fix went out for this. Our internal tests & reports from other customers indicate that the 503 debugger issue is no longer being returned.

If you see other problems with the debugger at all, please [contact CloudFlare](http://support.cloudflare.com/cgi/discussion/new).

Comment: That is indeed splendid and thank you for following up. I'm going to test it for a while and report back. Glad to see cloudflare immersed in the community ;)